# Creating 'from' and 'to' branch data

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a text file which I am reading from. It looks something like this:

```
#from |   to   |  value

1         -       ---
          2       100
3         -       ---
          4       300
          5       400
          6       500
7         -       ---
          8       700
          9       800
```

I need a way to represent this data in **from : to : value** form.

I know how to read the text file line by line, however, the tricky part is that there can be multiple branches such as from 3 to 4, from 3 to 5, from 3 to 6....

How can i represent this data in such a way that I can later loop over and read from?

Cheers

EDIT: I have tried to create one list containing all the data eg. [ [3, [ (4, 300), (5,400), (6,500)]...] ] but I could not get it to work, and it seems to be very inefficient. Open to any ideas!!

Comment: Either use pandas DataFrames. Or loop through the file and memorize the most recently seen `from` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read each line and use for loop.

Here is the text file look like
[image]

And the code as following

```
result = []

with open("/Users/l2017006/Documents/fun/test/aa.csv") as f:
    tmp_from = 0
    for i in  f.readlines():
        line_element = i.split()
        if len(line_element) == 3:
            tmp_from = line_element[0]
            result.append([tmp_from])
        else:
            result[-1].append([(line_element[0], line_element[1])])


for i in result:
    print(i)
```

And  result is as following

```
['1', [('2', '100')]]
['3', [('4', '300')], [('5', '400')], [('6', '500')]]
['7', [('8', '700')], [('9', '800')]]
```